# Finding the nth power in a list

Tags: python, list

You are given an array with positive numbers and a non-negative number N. You should find the N-th power of the element in the array with the index N. If N is outside of the array, then return -1.

```py
def index(array, n):
    selected_number = []
    if n > len(array):
        return -1
    else:
        selected_number.append(array[n])
        total = selected_number[0]
    return total ** n
```

This is the code I wrote. It does the second part correctly but when the variable n is greater the array list the output doesn't output -1 like it is supposed to. How does this not work?

Comment: try `n > len(array) -1`. The maximum valid index is `len(array) - 1`

Comment: Why do you have a list of selected numbers, where you put one number, just to read that same number in the next line? Why not just `return array[n] ** n`?

Comment: The code shown works fine except for the case where `n` is equal to the length of the array, or for negative values. Regarding the "equal" case this is essentially a typo: `>` should be `>=`. Alternately, we can use more sophisticated code to check negative indices as well. If there is any real question here, it's "what indices are valid?", for which I have linked a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner:

`result = arr[n]**n if n<len(arr) else -1`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use:

```
def index(array,n):
    try:
        return array[n] ** n
    except IndexError:
        return -1
```

So, if there is an error with index it will return -1.

Comment: It's easier to ask forgiveness than to get permission ;)

Comment: Python `Zen` is helpful ... ;-)

Comment: ... and horrified!  ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Another one liner:

```py
def index(array, n):
    return sum(array[n:n+1])**n or -1
```